# Adding a unique constraint on xsd single field

Tags: python, xml, xsd

I have the following xml.

```
 <Movies>
     <Title>
         <Platform>Hulu</Platform>
         <PlatformID>50019855</PlatformID>
         <UnixTimestamp>1431892827</UnixTimestamp>
     </Title>
     <Title>
         <Platform>Hulu</Platform>
         <PlatformID>50019855</PlatformID>
         <UnixTimestamp>1431892127</UnixTimestamp>
     </Title>
 </Movies>
```

I then have the following xsd which validates the above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="Movies">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Title" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Platform" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="PlatformID" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="UnixTimestamp" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

How would I add in a unique constraint such that `PlatformID` is a unique valud, and the validation fails if there is ever a duplicate value, such as in the above xml?

Comment: ***You've asked this same question twice, for some reason.***  I suggest that you delete this version as I've already taken the time to improve [your other version of the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30428140/290085), and already provided a better answer there than any of the answers that appear here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the `xs:unique` constaint within the `Movies` level, not within `Title` level. If it is within the `Title` level, it will only check for duplicates **within** that node:

XML

```
<Movies>
    <Title>
        <Platform>Hulu</Platform>
        <PlatformID>50019855</PlatformID>
        <UnixTimestamp>1431892827</UnixTimestamp>
    </Title>
    <Title>
        <Platform>Hulu</Platform>
        <PlatformID>50019855</PlatformID>
        <UnixTimestamp>1431892127</UnixTimestamp>
    </Title>
</Movies>
```

XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Movies">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Title" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Platform" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="PlatformID" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                            <xs:element name="UnixTimestamp" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:unique name="uniquePlatformID">
            <xs:selector xpath=".//Title/PlatformID"/>
            <xs:field xpath="."/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: This works but uses an overly complicated XPath for the selector.  See [**my answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30428722/290085) to [*your other copy of this question*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30428140/290085) (**why ask twice?**)  for a simpler way to express your uniqueness constraint.