# Set XSD duplicate constraint at document-level

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I have the following XML:

```
<Movies>
    <Title>
        <Platform>Hulu</Platform>
        <PlatformID>50019855</PlatformID> <!-- Reject xml based on duplicate PlatformID -->
        <UnixTimestamp>1431892827</UnixTimestamp>
    </Title>
    <Title>
        <Platform>Hulu</Platform>
        <PlatformID>50019855</PlatformID> <!-- Reject xml based on duplicate PlatformID -->
        <UnixTimestamp>1431892127</UnixTimestamp>
    </Title>
</Movies>
```

The following XSD validates, however I want it to reject it because **it has a duplicate `PlatformID`**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="Movies">
  <xs:complexType>

    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Title" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Platform" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="PlatformID" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="UnixTimestamp" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      <xs:unique name="uniquePlatformID">
        <xs:selector xpath=".//Title/PlatformID"/>
        <xs:field xpath="."/>
      </xs:unique>

      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

What would be the correct XSD here, to reject it based on the duplicate `PlatformID` above? What is wrong with the XSD I'm currently using? I believe the issue is that I'm trying to create a unique constraint within the `Title` node, whereas I need to create it document-wide at the `Movies/Title/PlatformID` level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.  Just move the `xs:unique` up to be part of the definition of the root `Movies` element since the scope of uniqueness is intended to be across the entire document (within the root element, that is):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Movies">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Title" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Platform" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="PlatformID" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
              <xs:element name="UnixTimestamp" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="uniquePlatformID">
      <xs:selector xpath="Title"/>
      <xs:field xpath="PlatformID"/>
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Then you'll get an error such as the following about duplicate values for `PlatformID`:

> [Error] try.xml:11:42: cvc-identity-constraint.4.1: Duplicate unique
>   value [50019855] declared for identity constraint "uniquePlatformID"
>   of element "Movies".